# Django form - How to autofill field from another

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I would like to autofill my `Kpi fieldd` by extracting its value in the `name field`
For example : here `kpi = name.split("-")[6]` which equal to `CPC` string. How can I do that please?

[image]

```
class UserCampaigns(models.Model):
    dsp_choices =(
        ('Amazon', 'Amazon'),
        ('Amobee', 'Amobee'),
        ('AppNexus', 'AppNexus'),
        ('Digiteka', 'Digiteka'),
        ('DV 360', 'DV 360'),
    )
    kpi_choices = (
        ('CPA', 'CPA'), ('CPC', 'CPC'),
        ('CPD', 'CPD'), ('CPL', 'CPL'),
        ('CPM', 'CPM'), ('CPV', 'CPV'),
        ('CTR', 'CTR'), ('Vsibility', 'Visibility'),
        ('VTR', 'VTR'), ('LTR', 'LTR'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey(CampaignNamingTool, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dsp = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=dsp_choices)
    budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    kpi = models.CharField(max_length=10) #choices=kpi_choices)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<select id="kpi">
    <option>...</option>
</select> 

<input id="kpi_input">

<script>
    const kpiSelection = document.getElementById("kpi");
    const kpiInput = document.getElementById("kpi_input");

    var kpiValue = kpiSelection.options[kpiSelection.selectedIndex].text;
    kpiInput.value = kpiValue.split('-')[6]
</script>
```

Get the text of the selected option and set the value of the input field. Create this as a function that will be triggered when the selected option change.

Comment: Thanks, I have already my input fiels in my django forms.py. Is there possible to do it in django model?

Comment: @aba2s If it is based on a fixed value only depending on the selected option, you can exclude that field from the form, but deal with the selected value in your view instead before saving. If not and you don't want to use JS then how are you going to reload the form when the user change the selected option.